# No other users can access external hdd since upgrade to 12.10

Tags: 12.10, mount, hard-drive, external-hdd

Since upgrading to Ubuntu 12.10 no other user can access the external hdd. This is awkward as its a family pc and we use the hdd to store music and save backups across the several accounts.

The external hdd seems to mount just to my account now, i.e. /media/[user1]/[ext hdd], and while all the other users can see the drive mounted they can not access as they just receive a file location error. From their perspective it is mounted just in my profile and not in theirs.

I have tried editing the properties of the hdd to allow others to view and create files on the hdd but that has not changed anything. I have also read that this is a new feature to Ubuntu 12.10, the way it mounts via /media/[user]/.

So is there a way to have it mount to all the other user accounts too?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one simple and best solution would be to give full permission to /media, since its a family pc and none else will use. it can be done by

sudo chmod 777 /media

if asked for password give it. to do this you need to have admin privileges.

Comment: You little rockstar :-D That's got it working perfect, the accounts started backing up as soon as I logged in with no errors. Thank you.